# C# Xamarin Clickable LinearLayout

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, android-linearlayout, clickable

I want to make a clickable LinearLayout. I already set the Layout to Clickable and Focusable, but how can I write code in mainActivity.cs like:

```
LinearLayout.ItemClick += LinearLayout_ItemClick;

void LinearLayout_ItemClick(Object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do something...
    }
```

Because it says that a Layout doesn't have the clickable function!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would it be `layout.Click` instead of `layout.ItemClick`?

`ItemClick` is intended for lists, and allows you to define the behaviour when clicking on the elements of those lists

Update :

Your argument will not be `AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs` anymore, I have no pc right here but if you type `.Click +=`, visual studio's intellisense should suggest you to add a handler and would create it for you with the right type :-)

Hope it solves your problem!

Comment: Now it says: "No overload for 'LinearLayout_Click' matches delegate 'EventHandler'"

Comment: Because your argument will not be AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs

Comment: What would it be then?

Comment: I have no pc right here but if you type `.Click +=`, visual studio's intellisense should suggest you to add a handler and would create it for you with the right type :-)